# How to create a pie chart from a text column data only using pandas dataframe directly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which I read using

```
pd.read_csv()
```

In the file name I have a column with *Female* or *Male* and I would like to create a pie visualization *Female* or *Male*. This means, my legend will contain the color and type ( *Female* or *Male*) and in the pie chart, there will be the Prozent of each gender.

An example of a data set will be:

```
['Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female']
```

A possible solution is to count the number of *Female* and the number of *Male* and then to generate the ṕlot.

Is there a simpler way using the *dataframe* data directly to generate the pie chart?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series(['Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female'])
s.value_counts(normalize=True).plot.pie(autopct='%.1f %%', ylabel='', legend=True)
```

[image]